# How I can loop through the similar objects in state and push them into object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got several variables in my `this.state` object:

```
this.state = {
      draw_number: '',
      user_number_1: '',
      user_number_2: '',
      user_number_3: '',
      user_number_4: '',
      user_number_5: '',
      user_number_6: '',
    }
```

How I can loop through them and add them in the following object:

```
results {
  numbers: [],
  draws: x
}
```

**This is my current solution:**

```
 this.state = {
      draw_number: '',
      user_number_1: '',
      user_number_2: '',
      user_number_3: '',
      user_number_4: '',
      user_number_5: '',
      user_number_6: '',
    }
  }

  submitHandler = () => {
    let results = {};
    for (let i=1; i<=6; i++) {
      results = this.state['user_number_' + i];
    }
    console.log(results);
  }
```

Right now I cannot console.log my 'results' object

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question? How should it be different from your own solution?

Comment: I want to loop through my state values and add them to the `results` object that will be later passed via AJAX call to the server

Comment: Your issue is that you're overwriting results within your loop every time instead of appending/push/add/etc...

Comment: One solution is create an object with number properties `let numbers = { number_1: '', etc.. }`and while saving, using Object.keys, you can push them into array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could extract the `draw_number` property from the state and use that as `draws` and then use `Object.keys` on the rest of the properties in your state and use those values as the `numbers` array.

```
submitHandler = () => {
  let { draw_number: draws, ...rest } = this.state;
  let results = {
    numbers: Object.keys(rest).map(key => rest[key])
    draws,
  };
  console.log(results);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [spread operator][https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax].
This way you can copy all keys from object (new in ECMAScript 2018):

```js
const myFriend = {name: 'George', age: 12}
const mySuperFriend = { ...myFriend, superpowers: true }
```

NOTE
you shouldn't mutate the state object directly in react.
Instead, create a new object and `setState` it